# Inverted Triangle in Python-not running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program to print an inverted triangle in python.
When I was running it in *Sublime Text 3* it did not run.
By that, I mean that it did not even print a syntax error.

```
def triangle():
    x = 1
    for i in range(11,1):
      print('*' * 10 - x)
    x = x + 1
    return
triangle()
```

Comment: ...you have a `return` outside of a function, and it's not giving you any error output? It sounds like you may not actually be running the code you think you are.

Comment: Is it a requirement to run inside Sublime? Please try to lessen the scope of the problem. E.g. run the script somewhere else

Comment: @cricket_007 The code is not working in Sublime, Cloud 9, and even IDLE

Comment: @MaanyaArora When you ask a question on SO, try to list the things you've already tried. Also, your question isn't really a Sublime Text issue, so by adding that you muddy the waters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range is empty

```
>>> list(range(11,1))
[]
```

Therefore, nothing is printed as the loop does nothing

You need the step parameter

```
>>> list(range(11,1,-1))
[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

<sub>Before thinking the code "isn't working", just put a `print('calling function')` and `print('in function')` in the code while you test it</sub>

Comment: You'll also want `print('*' * (10 - i))` @MaanyaArora