# From Triangle to Inverted Triangle in Python

Tags: python

```
def triangle():
    n=int(input('Enter the number of lines for this triangle: '))
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print ((n-i)*' '+i*'* ')
triangle()
```

As per [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508575/inverted-triangle-in-python-not-running), I have edited my code. It is working now, but not in the way I hoped. Please tell a way in which I can make the triangle become inverted(backward) instead of like a regular triangle. Thanks.

Comment: Reverse the direction of the `range` in your `for` loop.  With all of the "triangle" programs posted on line, I'm surprised you're not finding help in your research.  What search terms did you use?

Comment: If you're on windows just use `Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow`

Comment: @Prune Thank you and I searched Inverted Triangle but none of the results were fairly clear to me.

Comment: Also, I see that the solution you need is already in the answer you accepted to your previous question.

Comment: @user3483203 Mmm... Yes, I just tried that, the triangle is now upside down and so is the rest of my screen.

Comment: Glad it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `range(n,0,-1)`:

```
>>> triangle()
Enter the number of lines for this triangle: 5
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    *
```

And for a bit more fun:

```
def triangle(reverse=False):
    n=int(input('Enter the number of lines for this triangle: '))
    if reverse:
        r = range(n,0,-1)
    else:
        r = range(1,n+1)
    for i in r:
        print ((n-i)*' '+i*'* ')

>>> triangle()
Enter the number of lines for this triangle: 5
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * * 
>>> triangle(reverse=True)
Enter the number of lines for this triangle: 5
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    *
```